# Using SC.Timer to blink cursor

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a cursor blink every 2.5 seconds but I'm not sure how to use the `SC.Timer` object. The method I should be calling is `_drawInsertionPoint(rect,context)` every 2.5 seconds.

I found this:

```
var timer = SC.Timer.schedule({
target: this
action: '_drawInsertionPoint(rec,context)',
interval: 100,
repeats: YES,
until: Time.now() + 1000
}) ;
```

But I don't know how to pass in the parameters in action; it won't work.

Any insight to this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an anonymous function as the `action` parameter, like this:

```
var timer = SC.Timer.schedule({
    target: this
    action: function() { _drawInsertionPoint(rec,context); },
    interval: 100,
    repeats: YES,
    until: Time.now() + 1000
});
```

Comment: And how can I call this or does it automatically get called

Comment: It works the same way as your code, but instead of evaluating the string, the timer will call the function.